# centos/redhat: change open files ulimit without reboot?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, ulimit

The hard limit of the number of open files is set to 1024 on my machine.

- I changed /etc/security/limits.conf and added 'idror hard nofile 65000'.
- In my shell I tried ulimit -n 65000. I get 'ulimit: value exceeds hard limit'
- In my shell I tried ulimit -Hn 65000. I get 'ulimit: can't raise hard limits'

So how can I increase the setting for the limit of open files without reboot?

Comment: After a `limits.conf` change, you need to log out and back in.

Answer (score 8):

You can just change it as root. For example:

```
$ ulimit -n  
4096
$ ulimit -n 8192
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
$ sudo bash                    
# ulimit -n                    
4096
# ulimit -n 8192                  
# su - normaluser                 
$ ulimit -n                       
8192
```